# why is my wp_enqueue_script not working?

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress

i dont seem to know what is wrong with my code in my functions.php file, I am using a child theme that i made based on the twentyten theme.

here is my code hopefully you guys can tell me whats wrong with it.

```
function style_n_scripts(){

wp_enqueue_script('jquery' );

    wp_register_script('style-js', get_template_directory_uri() . 'stylehercloset.js', array( 'jquery' ), NULL, false );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'style-js' );

}

add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts','style_n_scripts');
```

Answer (score 3):

Add a slash before your name file.

```
wp_register_script('style-js', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/stylehercloset.js', array( 'jquery' ), NULL, false );
```

Comment: You are using a child theme, so you have to use `get_stylesheet_directory_uri()` instead of `get_template_directory_uri()`.